# Transferring file from remote Linux to Local Windows

Tags: powershell, shell, ssh, command-line, scp

I am trying to transfer a file from a remote linux device to my local Windows10 pc which has SSH.

I am running the command `scp myusername@remotepc:/home/links/myusername/CA1/final.png C:\Users\sinan koramaz\Desktop\Clasess`

which prompts me to enter my password.

After it is either;

giving me permission denied
just freezing the powershell completely
or says file transferred but even after searching the whole PC, I can't find the file.

I am aware similar questions had been asked but the ones I could find were all about Mac's or linux pc's.

Comment: The destination path has a space in it. You should quote it

Comment: You need to set up passwordless SSH by copying the keys to take care of the password prompt issue. Alternatively, you may use Expect for interactive automation or a Python script using an SSH/SCP library (say Paramiko) that can handle the SSL authentication.